# Photoshop bevel and emboss parameters depending on document dpi

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects

I tried appying the same bevel and emboss paramters to two texts: one text was written in a document 800x600 px with **72 pixels/inch**, the other one in a document 800x600 px with **300 pixels/inch**.

In both cases had the text a size of 170pt.
The bevel and emboss parameters I used are the following

- Inner bevel
- Depth 200%
- size 15px
- soften 0px

I obtained quite a different results:

- glossy text with the 72 pixel/inch
- something not so nice with the 300 pixels/inch: the emboss seemed to work only on the edge of the text and was not affecting the center

Why do I get different results?
I actually thought the paramters were only relative to the text size (170pt), not to the document resolution.

I did try increasing the depth or the size, but I could not come to the same result. But there must be a way to scale it properly so that the two results match. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop's effects are pixel-based, raster not vector.

This means, as you've discovered, that changing your image's scale/resolution will change the effects too.

As far as I'm aware, this is a no-fix situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am however not changing the resolution of the same picture, but working with 2 docunents with different resolution (one for use on the screen and one for printing on paper). So there must be a way to set the parameters in such a way that I get a glossy text also for printing purposes. I am basically looking for a smart way instead of trying values randomly

Comment: You could try /4.12, but I've found it's not that simple.

Comment: Of course, you could save all the extra work & only make the high-res version, then shrink at export. Whole lot less effort. I do that with my own work - everything on one 'master' file, then I have a script that just pumps out all the variants I need for production, right at the end.